# How to pass down functions as a prop with the new React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am practicing the new React hooks and I came with another question once again, cause I simply cannot find this on the internet.

I am trying to pass down a function as a prop from a function component to another function component. I am managing the states with the useState hook. In a class-based component you'd use `this.props.addTodo(this.state)` where I now have `addTodo.addTodo(content)`. This feels kinda hacky. Isn't there a better way to do this? See the full code below.

Main app component

```js
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import Todos from './Todos';
    import AddTodo from './AddTodo';


    function App() {

      const [todos, setTodos ] = useState([
          {id: 1, content: 'buy some milk'},
          {id: 2, content: 'play mario kart'}
      ]);

      const deleteTodo = (id) => {
        const Todos = todos.filter(todo => {
          return todo.id !== id
        });

      setTodos(Todos)
      }

      const addTodo = (todo) => {
        console.log(todo) //Here I want to do something with the new todo value, which I got from the add todo component
      }

      return (
        <div className="todo-app container">
          <h1 className="center blue-text">Todo's</h1>
          <Todos todos={todos} deleteTodo={deleteTodo} />
          <AddTodo addTodo={addTodo} />
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

The add todo's component

```js
    import React, { useState } from 'react';

    function AddTodo(addTodo) {

        const [content, setContent] = useState('');

        const handleChange = (e) => {
            setContent(e.target.value);
        }

        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            addTodo.addTodo(content);
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Add new todo</label>
                    <input type="text" onChange={handleChange}/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default AddTodo;
```

I am pretty new to actively sharing my code and asking help in this way. So please let me know if there is more info needed on this subject!

Best regards

Comment: "This feels kinda hacky." It wont if you named functional component argument to be `props` (which it actually is). Or use destructuring `function AddTodo({ addTodo }) {`

Comment: @Prgreat did you getting an error ?

Comment: I completely forgot about deconstructing! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

destruct a prop obj

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function AddTodo({addTodo}) {

    const [content, setContent] = useState('');

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setContent(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addTodo(content);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>Add new todo</label>
                <input type="text" onChange={handleChange}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```